# Regression: calculate mean weight, when you know R =0.5, mean lenght, mean weight and both SD

Tags: regression

For a small quiz I am unsure about this question. Please help me out :) :

We perform a regression for the relationship between heigh and weight. 
What is given: 
R = 0.5, mean height is 176 centimeters, and SD is 7 centimeters.
The mean weight is 74 kilograms with a SD of 5 kilograms.

The question: What is the average height of a person who weighs 86kg?

Comment: There is not usually a linear relationship between height and weight

Comment: You can get an estimate using the point on the regression line where weight=74 kilograms. The estimate may not be very accurate if the linear relationship is weak.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The regression line suggested by [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) can be written as

$$\dfrac{\hat{y}-\bar{y}}{s_y}= r_{xy} \left(\dfrac{x-\bar{x}}{s_x}\right)$$